# D3 - conditionally add maker to line

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/k8d1rGcU2CQHJlRIaETa?p=preview

I have 3 three bars that are made with a start and finish position.

The start position can be higher or lower than the finish.

I want to draw arrows on the bars to illustrate if the start is before or after the finish.

I'm drawing the lines on bars and adding the arrow with `marker-end`

Is it possible to conditonally add `marker-end` or `marker-start`

That way I could show if its going up or down.

Comment: if you return `null` for an `attr()` the attribute is not added

Comment: This question is so very close to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186174/d3-svg-css-rotate-line-around-centre-using-css/53188853#53188853 that I feel they should probably have been one question - "How to add arrows based on the start and finish values"